# Compare 2 list data with partial match and return aggregated data from both list

Tags: c#, linq

I have below 2 lists where I need to do partial match of `masterData's` **Name** with `sampleData's` **Name** and need output as `Name` from `Master` and `Version` from `SampleData`. (`Name_version`)

```
var masterData = new List<Master>
{
    new Master{Name = "Master1"},
    new Master{Name = "Master2"},
    new Master{Name = "Master3"},
    new Master{Name = "Master4"}
};

var sampleData = new List<SampleData>
{
    new SampleData{Name = "this is master1", Version = "20.01"},
    new SampleData{Name = "this is master1", Version = "20.02"},
    new SampleData{Name = "this is master3", Version = "23.01"},
    new SampleData{Name = "this is master5", Version = "20.01"}
};
```

Expected output **I am looking for, `Name` from `Master` and `Version` from `SampleData`** when there is partial match.

```
 var output = new List<SampleData>
{
    new SampleData{Name = "Master1_20.01"}, 
    new SampleData{Name = "Master1_20.02"},
    new SampleData{Name = "Master3_23.01"}
};
```

I tried till partial match, where I prepare one long string for all `Master` data with "|" delimiter, but not able to figure out how to prepare my desired output.

```
var regexPattern = masterData.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, md) => current + $"{md.Name}|");

var output = (from data in sampleData
    let IsMatched = Regex.IsMatch(data.Name, regexPattern.TrimEnd('|'), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    where IsMatched
         select data).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution without regex:

```
var output = 
    sampleData.Select(sd =>
    {
        var master = masterData.FirstOrDefault(m => sd.Name.ContainsIgnoreCase(m.Name));
        return (master is null ? null
                : new SampleData { Name = $"{master.Name}_{sd.Version}" });
    })
    .Where(sd => sd != null)
    .ToList();
```

Where `ContainsIgnoreCase()` is an extension method that looks like this:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool ContainsIgnoreCase(this string s, string value)
    {
        return (s.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
    }
}
```

**[Online demo](https://rextester.com/XRTOF92021)**.

Answer (score 1):

Change your select to this:

```
select data.Name.Split()[2] + "_" + data.Version
```

It seems also you have your first letter uppercase, in this case you can use the following extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string FirstCharToUpper(this string input) =>
        input switch
        {
            null => throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input)),
            "" => throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(input)} cannot be empty", 
              nameof(input)),
            _ => input.First().ToString().ToUpper() + input.Substring(1)
        };
}
```

So your select would be like this:

```
select data.Name.Split()[2].FirstCharToUpper() + "_" + data.Version
```